# MySQL select dynamic column names from another table

Tags: php, mysql, pivot-table

I have three MySQL tables.  I'd like to select the rows from one table and use them as the column names in my select statement.

Below are my three tables.

**locations**

```
id   location_name
1    London
2    Barnes
```

**bookings**

```
id   location_id    voucher_code    places    price
1    1              DISC100         2         620
```

**vouchers**

```
id    voucher_code    net_value
1     DISC100         155
2     DISC200         120
```

The current SQL I am using is below.  However, you will notice that i'm having to manually select the column names in my case statements.  I would like to make this dynamic.

**Current SQL**

```
select 
`locations`.`location_name`, 
"All time" as dates, 
ifnull(bookings.places, 0) as places, 
    case when vouchers.net_value = 155 then 1 else 0 end as voucher155, 
    case when vouchers.net_value = 135 then 1 else 0 end as voucher135, 
    case when vouchers.net_value is null then 1 else 0 end as paidbycard 
from 
    `locations` 
inner join `bookings` on `locations`.`id` = `bookings`.`location_id` 
left join `vouchers` on `bookings`.`voucher_code` = `vouchers`.`voucher_code` 
group by `locations`.`id`
```

The section that I would like to make dynamic is below.

```
case when vouchers.net_value = 155 then 1 else 0 end as voucher155, 
case when vouchers.net_value = 135 then 1 else 0 end as voucher135, 
case when vouchers.net_value is null then 1 else 0 end as paidbycard
```

The reason that I need to make these columns dynamic is because the user is able to add / delete vouchers, so the columns need to change as the vouchers do.

The new SQL should result in the following result:

```
location_name    dates      places    netValue155    netValue135   paidbycard
London           All time   2         155.00         0.00          465.00
```

So just to summarise, I want to select the sum of net_value from `vouchers` as the column name.

Can anyone help?

Comment: The generic term for this is pivoting, for your information. It's a notorious pain in the neck in MySQL.

Comment: @OllieJones Luckily, the OP has tagged with PHP. Pain gone -although an aggregating clause with no aggregating functions should remain a cause for concern.

Comment: Is there not an easy solution?

Comment: Try to use a stored procedure with a cursor, then you can count how many vouchers do you have an then make a unique select

Comment: [My pivot blog](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pivot) gives code to generate the SQL to do the pivoting.